# Java swing editable line drawing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am writing a zigzag drawer as my school assignment. Basically what is expected is to be able to draw zigzags on a canvas, to be able to move vertices of the zigzags and to be able to move the entire zigzag. Also we can change the color and thickness of the zigzags.

I could manage to draw zigzags, a left click starts and subsequent left clicks continues the zigzag, and a right click finishes it. In this way i can draw several zigzags. 
What i can not do is how i can make the vertices of the zigzags movable? I am keeping the point coordinates in an arraylist of type mypoint which consists of x, y and depth values. I am drawing all the painting on a canvas which is an extended class of JPanel. in the paintcomponent method i call drawline methode for every vertex in the list. As these are just paintings i cannot figure out how i will detect that the user is clicking on the vertex. Can i have little button like controllers when clicked will do the job i want. i tried to use labels and standard buttons, but neither can i position them appropriately nor are they too large to be just handlers for vertices.

Do you have suggestions on these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have two modes of operations, which must be chosen by the user by selecting a radio button, for example: one for drawing zigzags, and the other one for selecting vertices.

While the chosen mode is "zigzag", the mouse clicks allow drawing zigzags as you have already implemented. When the chosen mode is "vertex selection", then a mouse click could find a vertex whose distance from the clicked point is less than 3 pixels, and the dragging of the mouse could move the vertex from its original position, following the mouse pointer.

You could inform the user about the selected vertex by displaying a small squere around the vertex.